# where sequence values are stored in Oracle?

Tags: sequence-sql

> While dealing with sequence in oracle we might get confused that where these sequence values are getting stored.
>   So here is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to write the following query:

select Last_Number Numm from user_sequences where 
sequence_name='Name_Of_Sequence';

or

select * from user_sequences where 
sequence_name='Name_Of_Sequence';

In this output just see Last_Number column this is nothing but value associated with that sequence.

And to see all the existing sequences write the following query:

select * from user_sequences;